# Intellij does not recognize Griffon variables?

Tags: intellij-idea, griffon

Hi there i am trying to learn more about Griffon, but using IntelliJ it seems that code completion is not correct and variables are not recognized. So i am surely doing something wrong. I have created a new Griffon project and various things are not recognized. Also when i try to add a MenuBar for example code completion seems not to work. When i run it everything seems ok! So what am i missing???

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known Griffon bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-433) fixed for 0.9.5.

The Griffon library manages the intellisense by itself, and, unfortunately, in this version it's broken. You can fix it by opening `griffon.gdsl` file, copying it into your project (or editing in-place and repacking into the jar), fixing two unclosed string literal problems there, and re-activating the script using the link at the top of the editor. This would bring you code completion.

Another option is to wait for Griffon 0.9.5 release or try the [snapshot build](http://bamboo.ci.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-RELEASE09X/latest/artifact/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed it using your suggestion of correcting the string literal and repacking. For people that need to do the same, the griffon.gdsl file is located inside the 'griffon-cli-0.9.4.jar' file.